# SVG absolute units incorrect

Tags: html, svg, absolute, units-of-measurement

I am trying to create a ruler in a mobile app, which will scale correctly regardless of the model of iPhone or Android. I figured the simplest way is to create an SVG element with absolute units. However, this is not scaling correctly on either my browser or phone (85% of proper size on my Macbook pro, 2/3 proper size on my android phone). I've performed extensive googling for a default SVG DPI, absolute units, converting absolute values, scaling, etc, and found nothing useful.

Here is the simplified code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ruler</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="6cm" height="10cm" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g fill="none" stroke="none">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10cm" id="backboard" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is **no** 'default SVG DPI' - the DPI is a value of the screen - which is not the same across devices and especially among mobile devices.

Assuming you *know* the DPI of the screen the pixel-to-mm formula is this:

```
mm = (pixels * 25.4) / DPI
```

---

In other words unless you know the DPI value of the screen you can't have real world unit measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, physical units aren't tied to any real world basis, such as actual screen DPI.

They are actually based on the "standard" CSS DPI of 96 (ie. 96 "CSS pixels").  I think the CSS spec says browsers are free to adjust the DPI to other values so that, for example, "1in" is actually one inch. But in practice none of them bother.

So, unfortunately, you will need to establish the device's true DPI and scale your coordinate values appropriately.